# Games Giveaway Round 2- Don't fear the reapers! -Updated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotional-grant

> **Update:** Just about everyone was selected. Emails are out/going out with updates.

Welcome to the New Gaming Promotional Grant Round 2!
Have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information here for Mass Effect 3.

All users with at least 300 reputation are eligible to receive Mass Effect 3.

The catch? Simple - ask 8 questions about your new game within the first 2 weeks of playing. If you don't get to ask 8 questions, no fear, you just sit out the next round.

For every Reaper you kill, you save one unicorn from poachers (huh?).

<strike>How to sign up: Fill out **this form** specifying which game you want.</strike>

Entries will be open until Friday 3/2 at 12pm EST. Selected entrants will be notified promptly.

- You can buy this game through Origin and then have the purchase reimbursed through Paypal. We can't use gifts for this round unfortunately.
- The reimbursement is only for the regular edition of the game. If you buy the deluxe versions, you can still get reimbursed for the price of the regular edition.
- If you fulfilled the commitment for the last round, you get this game. *Please still do fill out the form as usual!*

A few people didn't fulfill their commitment (and get to watch this round from the bench :P) and we will treat new applicants equally — so we do expect more than 20 copies of ME3 to be awarded in total (moar games please!).

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4059/8581 *(comments about this topic purged --badp)*

Comment: This round is ONLY ME3?  We're not offering any other games?  I am interested in ME3 (although it would really suck if I wasn't!), but I don't think there's going to be any shortage of content for it.  There are some other notable titles launching in the next month, so this is a little disappointing.  (Also, I was going to wait for it to be available on Steam which I'm sure it will eventually, but that's a quibble.)

Comment: Also, I think that only offering the one game is actually going to make meeting the question commitment difficult - I got FF13-2 last round and almost had trouble meeting my quota because a lot of the questions I had were already asked - this will only be a lot worse with a ton of copies of the same game out there.  I'm sure it's probably too late to expect you guys to reconsider, but I wish you would.

Comment: @Shinrai The last grant explained that participating didn't disqualify you from the next round, unlike how things were done last year...

Comment: @Stephen - I'm confused as to how that has anything to do with my concerns.  I think that's a good thing.  I just think the single game approach may make things more difficult than it has to be.  (Also, if somebody was in the last round, and met their quota so they automatically qualify for this round, what if they just don't like RPGs?  Do they get to keep their 'bye' until next time?)

Comment: Also, selfishly, I was hoping to score a copy of Silent Hill: Downpour out of this round. XD

Comment: @Shinrai Sorry, I thought your comment "There are some other notable titles launching in the next month, so this is a little disappointing" indicated that you were hoping to qualify for next month and wouldn't be able to get what you wanted then if you participated now.

Comment: @Stephen - No, I meant that we seem to be doing these grants one month apart now, so there are some other about-to-launch titles that could be offered in addition to ME3.

Comment: @Shinrai I hear your wish for Silent Hill! You never know, there may be another game giveaway round later on in March. But, who really knows :P

Comment: @SethRogers - That's nice to know (I am curious to know if the auto-in from the first round carries over if somebody decides to sit this one out).  I still think that we're going to be hard pressed to have HUNDREDS of valid, distinct questions about ME3 - assuming 30 copies at 8 questions apiece, that's 240 questions **from the promotional grant alone**, nevermind the large amount of traffic it'll probably generate anyway.  I just don't think this game is going to be nearly as deep as, say, Skyrim.

Comment: To ask directly, are we *really* expecting 200+ questions alone just from this? It seems unreasonable...that would make this one topic more popular than TF2 or swtor in our questions.

Comment: I am concerned that I would not be able to fulfill my commitment if I get the game because I think I will make progress more slowly than quite a few other people. Because of this, I think that whenever I get to any point in the game, many of the useful questions will have been asked already by people who played that part and were desperately trying to fulfill their commitments.

Comment: If a healthy amount of questions arised, I'm confident I could help in answering at least 8 of them, and if no such questions were there I'm confident I could ask 8 of them. I'm concerned that with a large body of questions all 20+ of us may well not be able to ask 8 *good* questions on the single topic.

Comment: Oh, for Amazon orders are you preordering (meaning we get the preorder bonus rifle in game?)

Comment: @murgatroid99 and Ben Brocka I hear ya. We'll evaluate on a case-by-case basis if needed, though it's a pretty vast game!

Comment: @SethRogers - Maybe best to clarify this in the post, as I was also still under the impression that CEs were getting full reimbursement.  (I mean, I'm happy to take the cost of the regular and cover the difference myself, but some other folks might not be.)

Comment: @SethRogers I've just been advised by Lauren that my order for KoA still hasn't shipped ... and might not ship for another week or more.  Good thing I still managed to get my questions in huh?

Comment: @Stephen if you have an extenuating circumstance like that you can certainly have more time to ask your questions, just let us know like you did. The problem with your order was that it takes a long time to ship to Canada, so with that in mind it might be better to choose Steam in the future if possible.

Comment: @Lauren Yeah, as I said in my answer below, my beef's with Amazon, not with SE ... and you in particular have been great in getting me some answers.  I actually had other book orders to place that have been routed to other vendors now, due to this ridiculous delay.

Comment: Totally understand!  Hopefully Steam will work out better for you. And again, sorry for the huge delay.

Comment: @Lauren No problem, live and learn!  Thanks for all your help in resolving this!

Comment: Quick question: do I send the re-reimbursement email when I enter the form, or after I've fulfilled my question quota?

Comment: so has everyone been notified already? I haven't heard a thing yet, so I hope my application didn't fail for some reason.

Comment: Anywhere with a complete list of winners?

Comment: @Fredy31 I'm not sure that information was ever public, but e-mails just went out now.

Comment: I picked a terrible, terrible time to not have the internet...

Comment: @MrSmooth So how are you writing this at the moment?

Comment: @Fredy31 I just recently got the net back, I didn't have the net while the giveaway was going on so I've missed out. Gunna be a while before I can afford this game, which I love.

Comment: Just as a follow up I was completely wrong, it's quiiiite easy to come up with over 200 questions for this game...I suspect you guys chose well when deciding on the answers-only rule

Comment: When can we expect reimbursements?

Comment: @Shinrai they are currently working on it. So hopefully in a few days.

Comment: @Lauren I haven't heard anything about reimbursement since the initial problems with my receipt.  Should I be expecting something soon?

Comment: @bwarner can you shoot me an email with more info? It's easier for me to look up if I know your email address and order. Sorry it's so much trouble!

Answer (score 6):

If I completed the first round, but I'm not interested in ME3, do I get into the next one that I enter into automatically still?

Comment: We're reevaluating the program with every round, so I can't guarantee right now- but it is likely.

Answer (score 3):

Any Canadians participating in this give away are warned that amazon.ca couldn't be slower to ship if they went out of business.

After 3 weeks my copy of KoA was still not shipped and there didn't seem to be any good reason for it, other than Amazon being terribly slow.

> Lauren Gundrum 11:05 AM (48 minutes ago)
>   to Stephen
>
> No problem. Just heard back from our office manager and it has been ordered but has not been shipped yet. She said Canadian orders can take up to 4 weeks to ship, unfortunately.

For the record, the turn around time for reimbursement from prior grant rounds has been fantastic and I appreciate all the hard work the SE staff does ... my beef is with Amazon.

***FOLLOW UP***

Lauren was able to cancel the order with Amazon and get my copy of KoA via Steam ... I thank her for all the aggravation this has caused her and look forward to getting everything downloaded and installed.

Comment: I didn't participate in the previous round, however the rounds before that my games would come from various retailers. My last game came from a local Edmonton company, and I think that solution worked out great.

Comment: @Stephen I recall similar problems trying to get Deus Ex: HR for the PC from Amazon.ca. Turns out that sometimes they delegate that to third-party sellers (for example, the [PC version of KoA](http://www.amazon.ca/Electronic-Arts-9891-Kingdoms-Amular/dp/B0044S8DA8/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1330657159&sr=8-5) says "Ships from and sold by biddeal.") which can throw a wrench into things. Normally amazon.ca is great if they're the ones doing shipping but for some reason they don't always on new releases.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks!  Nice to know it's not personal :-)  Nonetheless they lost this sale, several computer science books I was buying to prep for grad studies and who knows how much more before I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Does duplicate questions count towards the 8 question requirement?  Even though we do our best to try to avoid dupes sometimes its unavoidable since the wording on some questions may be very misleading.

(I suspect the answer is no, but I would just like to make it clear)

Comment: In general dupes don't count, but we look at each case individually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Honduras. I have a friend that has a U.S. Mailing Address. Can I use that address to get the game even if would have his name? It is basically a U.S. P.O. Box that forwards his mail to Honduras.

Related question: This would mean that I would receive the game 1 or 2 weeks after everyone else. Does this mean I would have less time to ask my questions than everyone else, or do the two weeks start counting after the game is in my hand?

Comment: If selected, we could only send it to you, I'm so sorry @marcelo!

Comment: @SethRogers and for my other question? If I receive my game 1 or 2 weeks after everyone else, do I have less/no time to fill my quota of questions?

Comment: the parameter is 2 weeks, so yes. Is there no way for you to buy the game and get paypal reimbursed (if you're selected that is)?

Comment: @SethRogers One more question, if I am selected and choose to use Amazon, will you guys make a preorder of the game, so that it's delivered exactly on release date? Will you send us the tracking number for the package?

Comment: Orders will be placed Friday afternoon- hopefully Amazon can deliver in time. As of now, we don't plan on sending everyone tracking numbers.

Comment: @SethRogers Thank you!

Comment: @SethRogers The question now has the Status-Completed tag. Does this mean I wasn't selected? I thought I had completed my quota for Round 1 :(

Comment: @SethRogers just got my confirmation, never mind my previous comment!

Answer (score 0):

When filling out the form, do I use the email address that is linked via my openID account, or the email address that is on my profile page?

Comment: Your primary email or the one on your profile page.

Answer (score 0):

- Does the "Reimburse me" option work for purchasing in Pound Sterling?
- Would we need to convert the value to dollars in the email body?
- Additionally, would a high resolution photograph of my receipt count as an electronic copy?, as I was planning to pick the game up in store.

Comment: A photo is fine if no receipt is on hand. We can reimburse Pounds through Paypal, though its still a conversion.